# Pass Data From Outside Function In Inner Function For Later Use

Tags: javascript

I have function `A` which defines another function `B`. B is passed as `argument` to another function `C` to `handle event` for later use. Function B `need data` from `function A`. Is it possible to pass data in this way ?

```
function A(B){

    var o = [1,2,3];


    B = function () {
      alert(this.blio); // data from A blio is undefined
    };

    B.blio = o; //bind data in property to B

    $('selector').C({ result: B}); //handle event
}
```

Comment: What is the behavior when you try it?

Comment: In function B this.blio is undefined.

Comment: What code is calling making the call to `B()`?

Comment: are you supposed to be passing `B` to `A` like you are above?

Answer (score 0):

By assigning B as a function in this way, you are declaring it as essentially a constructor for a new class.  `B.blio` is not a property on the object, but a static property on this class, and therefore cannot be referenced using `this`.

Instead, you should create a function on the prototype for the `B` class that will access the stored value on an instantiated object.  See the following for example:

```
var o = [1,2,3];

var B = function () {
    console.log("constructor called");
};

B.prototype.func = function () {
    console.log(this.blio);
}

function A(){
    var b = new B();//instantiate new object
    b.blio = o;//assign property to object
    b.func();//call prototype function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You override B parameter passed to function A when you assign

```
B = function () {
  alert(this.blio); // data from A
};
```

and then again override parameter B by trying to assign a property(like to an object) to a function

```
B.blio = o;
```

You should try this:

```
function A(B){

  var o = [1,2,3];

  B.myfunc=function () 
    {
       alert(this.blio);
    };
  B.blio = o; //bind data in property to B

$('selector').C({ result: B.myfunc()}); //handle event
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about a few things going on here related to scope.

```
function alpha(beta) {
    this.foo = 42;
    console.log('From inside alpha:', this.foo);

    var beta = function() {
        console.log('Form inside beta:', this.foo);
    };

    beta();
}

alpha();
```

When you execute the function alpha, **this** actually is the globally **window** object.

If you ran the code below in the console you would see that the alpha function just added the **foo** property to **window** and set it to 42.

```
console.log(window.foo);
```

From reading the comments in your code you are handling an event and can get the current value you need from something you are using as a data store, the key here is making sure you have access to the scope the needed values are in.

Posting more specific code would also be helpful to help you get a better answer. The role of all the nested functions is unclear.